# Postgresql not responding for a few seconds

Tags: linux, postgresql

From time to time I found errors in my logs indicating that the Postgresql server is not available for a few seconds:

> Jan 07 17:33:54 auth: Error: anvil-auth-penalty: Anvil queries timed out after 5 secs - aborting queries Jan 07 17:33:55 auth: Error: net_connect_unix(anvil-auth-penalty) failed: Permission denied
>
> Jan 07 17:33:55 auth: Error: net_connect_unix(anvil-auth-penalty) failed: Permission denied
>
> Jan 07 17:33:55 auth: Error: net_connect_unix(anvil-auth-penalty) failed: Permission denied
>
> Jan 07 17:33:58 auth: Error: pgsql: Query failed, aborting: SELECT password, allow_nets FROM mailbox WHERE username='user@domain.phoenix.hu' AND enablepop3secured=1 AND active=1
>
> Jan 07 17:33:58 auth: Error: sql(user@domain.hu,1.2.3.4,): Password query failed:
>
> Jan 07 17:33:58 auth: Error: sql(user2@domain.hu,2.3.4.5,): Password query failed: Not connected to database
>
> Jan 07 17:33:58 auth: Error: sql(user3@domain.hu,3.4.5.6,): Password query failed: Not connected to database
>
> Jan 07 17:33:58 auth: Error: sql(user4@domain.hu,7.8.9.10,): Password query failed: Not connected to database
>
> Jan 07 17:33:58 pop3: Error: Disconnected from auth server, aborting (client-pid=21781 client-id=1)

This log is taken from the `dovecot.log` file.
Is there a job which makes the server inresponsive for a few seconds I don't know about, or anything that could cause this? Thank you!